# Anonymous function in dynamically generated list producing SyntaxError

Tags: javascript

I want to place an onclick event inside a dynamically generated list. I can't use it as it is, like `updateRoomID(arg)`, because it would fire immediately. So I placed it inside an anonymous function, as advised by various sources online: `function (){updateRoomID(arg)}`. But this results in: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (". Developer tools says the problem is at `function()`.

The section of code it's in:

```
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    for (let i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        if (msg[i].beingserved == false) {
            listRooms.innerHTML += '<li id=' + msg[i].roomid +

                                   // Problem on following line.
                                   ' onclick=' + function () { updateRoomID(msg[i].roomid) } +
                                    '>' +
                                    '<a href="#">' +
                                    msg[i].roomid +
                                    '</a></li>';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(msg[i].roomid).remove();
        };
    };
};
```

I've tried it with the function as a string inside quotations marks: `<li id=' + msg[i].roomid +' onclick="function(){updateRoomID(msg[i].roomid)}">'`. I've tried placing the onclick handler in href link instead, and also replaced it with addEventListener. But I got the same error with these attempts.

If I try `function(){updateRoomID(arg)}()` with the parentheses behind, it fires immediately as expected.

I've been looking through it all day and can't figure out where the syntax error is. I'm quite unfamiliar with JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you console log document.clientlistForm, what it will return?
It may return undefined I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put a function in the `onclick` attribute. It contains JavaScript source code that should be executed.

What you should do in this case is put the function call as a string, but substitute in the value of the argument.

Using a template literal makes this easier.

```
listRooms.innerHTML += `
    <li id="${msg[i].roomid}" onclick="updateRoomId(${msg[i].roomid})">
      <a href="#">${msg[i].roomid}</a>
    </li>`;
```